# How can I fix unwanted logout in my web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, tomcat8, http-status-code-302

I am maintaining a web application written in JAVA, and I was tasked to upgrade the spring and spring-security dependencies. I updated them from version 3.x to 4.2, following this migration guide https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html.

The application is using XML configuration.

The configs that I had to update are the ff:

- HTTP headers (frame-options, xss-protection)
- login and logout settings
- csrf (disable)
- allowSemicolonHttpFirewall

I was able to make the application work when I debug it in NetBeans and did not encounter any problems.

But when I deploy the war file in Tomcat I keep encountering unwanted logout. The application works but after a while, I encounter a 302 (I noticed this from dev-tools network tab) and it redirects back to the login page and I'm forced to login again.

I tried finding a pattern on when it happens but I did not find any. It does not redirect on a specific page only, nor in a specific time span.

Any advice where should I look into to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please add complete server log from startup till you encountering logout